Flet - TextButton create a Grey container when i put style
I'm developing an application in Flet pyhton and I'm having a problem that when I put style on the TextButton it creates a gray box and doesn't show the text.
Before I put Style
    reset_password_text = ft.TextButton(
    text="Esqueci-me da Palavra-Passe", 
    on_click=lambda _: reset_password_button_clicked,
    )

enter image description here
After I put Style
    reset_password_text = ft.TextButton(
    text="Esqueci-me da Palavra-Passe", 
    on_click=lambda _: reset_password_button_clicked,
    style=ft.ButtonStyle(ft.TextStyle(size=20)),
    )

enter image description here
I tried put button with color Transparent and didn't work.Someone have this problem before?
Than you
I tried put button with color Transparent, add in a cointainer

First in style=ft.ButtonStyle(ft.TextStyle(size=20)) you are putting TexStyle in color attribute of ButtonStyle, becouse this is fist attribute of ButtonStyle and you should use insted style=ft.ButtonStyle(text_style=ft.TextStyle(size=20)) to aim directly to correct attribute.
